# Sending files from a TS server to a client workstation

Tags: sendmail, rdp, file-transfer, copy

Due to concerns with viruses, my boss wants to turn off the clipboard redirection on our TS/RDP servers - so that there is no possibility of copying files to the server. He does however, want to provide a way for our RDP users to copy/send pdfs and xlsx files from the TS server, to their local workstations.

I have been brain storming anyway to do this. I thought about writing/finding an smtp email client, putting it on the server, and setting it up so they can attach the files to an email, and email it to their workstation. That is a little klugy though.

Is there any other apps/software/methods out there that might provide the ability to send files from the TS server, to a clients workstation?

Comment: Don't the users already have an email client on the RDS server? Do they not use email when logged onto the RDS server?

Comment: No, in our scenario the user just remotes into to use our application. Their email is on their local workstation.

Comment: OK. I'm not understanding why you think it would be klugy to install an email client on the RDS server for the users to email the files to themselves. If that solves the problem then it's an acceptable solution.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is actually easy:
On the TS, share a folder for each user. By default, shares will have read-only access, so from their own machine, users may read the files from that share but at the same time, they may not write to that share. We use this. Additionally, you need to set the following GPO at the server:
Computer config. - adm. templates - Windows Components/Remote Desktop Services/Remote Desktop Session Host/Device and Resource Redirection ->enable "Do not allow drive redirection".

Comment: Thanks - I am not sure if this matches what we need - but I will forward this on to my boss.

Comment: Be ensured that it matches your needs. We wanted the same.